# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un valor de tipo day(DateTime) a un tipo int en php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy restando dos fechas de una DB, pero no quiero utilizar `DATEDIFF` y estoy usando lo siguiente:

Esta es mi consulta

```
$query = "SELECT ".$FechaI.", ".$FechaF." FROM ".$tabla
    ." WHERE ".$FechaI." BETWEEN '$f1' AND '$f2'";
```

Para restar estoy haciendo esto

```
$date1 = new DateTime($row[$FechaI]);
$date2 = new DateTime($row[$FechaF]);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Y quiero convertir este resultado de días a un entero para utilizarlo después en un recorrido en un `for`

```
echo '<br>'.$diff->days . ' días ';
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos :)

Comment: Hola, puede que este hilo de SO en ingles te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029167/php-converting-dateinterval-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás no es la mejor solución, pero creo que funcionará para tu caso

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2022-07-01 20:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2022-07-04 20:00');
$dias = ($date2->getTimestamp() - $date1->getTimestamp()) /60/60/24;
echo $dias; // result 3
```

O puedes forzar la conversión a entero usando `intval($varname)`.
Espero sea lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, agradezco tu ayuda, me sirvió :)